# Can I connect a Python GUI to a website using HTTP?

Tags: python, django, http, user-interface, tkinter

Is there a way to connect to a website from a Python Tkinter GUI using HTTP requests? Essentially, I want the following functionality:

1. Press a button on the GUI
2. A signal is sent to a website (from the GUI) that this button was pressed
3. Send information along with that signal

I only need to focus on the GUI side of this. I have no code to go along with this - I was just wondering if it's even possible.

Comment: You can, of course, make HTTP requests of any site you want, including fetching pages and submitting forms.  The `requests` module makes that very easy.  If you're talking about interacting with a web page, remember that means the page must be running in a browser somewhere.  Web pages don't just exist by themselves.  So, can you provide more detail about what you mean?

Comment: The website and GUI have both already been created. I essentially want it to be so that on the GUI side, it will send a signal such as "Hey, I am here, my name is - " and then the website displays that name.

Comment: Where is the web page being displayed?  On a browser on the same machine?  On a browser on a different machine?  Do you see the problem?  There isn't a 1-to-1 correspondence between your app and the web pages that your server might already have sent out.

Comment: The browser will be displayed on a different machine.

Comment: You can certainly send information to your web server.  That's easy.  However, once a web server has sent a page of HTML off to a browser, that connection is broken.  A web server cannot initiate any transfers to a browser.  It's a one-way conversation.  Updates have to be requested by the browser.  It's possible to use Javascript to have the browser keep asking for updates, but what if you have 9 people looking at the page?  Do you want them all to update?  If so, yes, that's possible.

Comment: Yes that's essentially what I need. The one way connection that would update for everyone looking at the page.

Comment: @TimRoberts: websites don't always return HTML pages - they can return other types of payloads.

Answer (score 1):

There are three components to what you ask.  Your GUI can send information to your web server using some URL you would have to invent.  It can be as simple as:

```
import requests
requests.get("http://example.com/information?name=Joe+Smith")
```

Then, your web server needs to respond to that request by saving the information somewhere.  Your web server also needs a similar request to return the information.  Then, your web page needs Javascript on a timer doing an AJAX request to fetch that info, and to change some field on the page in response.  That depends on what Javascript tools you're using.